# Vuforia Unity3D Cloud Recognition (switch between GameObjects)

Tags: unity-game-engine, cloud, vuforia

I am trying to replicate the 'Creating Cloud Recognition Apps in Unity - Augmented Reality - Vuforia (new)' video published by Vuforia developer portal. 
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILVpISTEcx4

However in the script they use

```
(ImageTracker)TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker(Tracker.Type.IMAGE_TRACKER);
```

but in the Viforia API there is no ImageTracker and seems obsolete

I did find ObjectTracker
https://developer.vuforia.com/library/sites/default/api/unity/classVuforia_1_1ObjectTracker.html

I tried using this but I don't it is correct

```
ObjectTracker tracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>();
```

Any help, suggestion or tutorials in the right direction would be very help full.

Thanks.

Comment: ImageTracker was indeed replace by ObjectTracker. I think it also needs the namespace to be added (using Vuforia;) when it used to be global

Comment: I added using Vuforia; It recognises the cloud targets but both the 'teapot' and the 'dragon' appear on top of each other. Do I have to add something similar to Tracker.Type.IMAGE_TRACKER to the code?

Comment: Either it finds both markers or you have both models under the same game object.

Comment: I have both models under the same ImageTarget. do I have to have multiple targets?

Comment: There is actually a multi tracker sample scene from Vuforia package, you should check it out.

Comment: Will have a look. Thanks.